# Computing a type from two unions/enums

Tags: typescript

Edit: Ok it appears that the code I posted below works flawlessly, so there's something else going on. Brb...

I am trying to specify a type from two enums or union types, but when I do I get the error

Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'x' does not exist in type 'y'

I thought maybe the problem was with using enums instead of a union type, but I haven't had any luck with that either. Also changing to interfaces and using `[context in keyof uiContexts]` didn't give any joy. I think there's something fundamental I'm misunderstanding here.

So I'm wanting to define inputs for various different program states.

```js
type inputs = 'up' | 'down' | 'left' | 'right'

type uiContexts = 'mainMenu' | 'subMenu'

class Parser {
  private contexts: {[context in uiContexts]: {[i in inputs]: () => void}} = {
    mainMenu: {
      up: () => {},
      down: () => {},
      left: () => {},
      right: () => {},
    },
    subMenu: {
      up: () => {},
      down: () => {},
      left: () => {},
      right: () => {},
    },
  }
}
```

expected: the type definition `{[context in uiContexts]: [i in inputs]: () => void}` to fit the data given.

Actual: compiling error `Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'subMenu' does not exist in type '{ mainMenu: { up: () => void; down: () => void; left: () => void; right: () => void; }`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Unfortunately, (or maybe *fortunately*), if I copy your exact code into [The Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play) it compiles without errors.   Please read the guidelines on what constitutes a [mcve] (specifically the "verifiable" part).  Good luck!

Comment: Seems to work to me: https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAlgdmArsAzlAvFA5IsWoA+2AJgPYDuc+RWANhAGbDXYBOMA5gBbMBQvoSFEQwAwqTjAIAD1QZsAWwCG8ALIQ4iFlhSIARus1Z+AY1pKUaAApLWKCKygBvXlChh2ANyVSoJiVKyKABczgDa-pIywLBwwmIB0SgAuqFOYTCxsUioqVAAFACUGAB8UJ6kMMQAvtXyLm5uymoaiGmujW64oUWlztUANB2dZJQ9xehlToPDjfRM433TQ51u7NzAi5P9K40znboGre2rwmBbU-uro3AXO7Nu85sFE5e7nes8d8uzV9W81SAA

Comment: Also `Record<uiContexts, Record<inputs, () => void>> ` is more readable and concise IMO